# Update Object Value In Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have one java script object which is iterating through handlebars. When I write `{{this.prop}}` this shows me "/bla/bla".

I want to update this property so that when I use `{{this.prop}}` it should return /alpha/bla/bla. I am looking for client-side manipulation. How can I do the same?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want achieve "/alpha/bla/bla" through string manipulation?

Comment: @hamzox Yes through string manipulation.

Comment: what was ur effort??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using: `src="'/alpha{{this.prop}}"`

Comment: Its not reflecting. My syntax is <img src="{{"/alpha"+this.prop}} /> . But its not appending /alpha.

Comment: Double quotes problem, use this: <img src="{{'/alpha'+this.prop}}" />

Comment: It render the same as it is src="{{'/alpha'+this.prop}}". when I inspect image path. It is not adding /alpha in front.

Comment: Give it a one more try, use: src="'/alpha{{this.prop}}".